# Why reading colored image as Gray Scale in OpenCv is different from convert same image from BGR to GRAY

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading colored image as GRAY then I read it as BGR. When I convert BGR to GRAY I found it different from the first one. Can anyone explain why and what the equation for converting and reading image in OpenCV?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img_c=cv2.imread("/home/image_7lbl.png",1) 
img_g=cv2.imread("/home/image_7lbl.png",0)  
img_cg=cv2.cvtColor(img_c,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(np.array_equal(img_g,img_cg))
False
```

[image]

Comment: I found the different with converting the color Green. in case reading GRAY, the value of the pixel will be 149 but in the convert is 150. in somehow the round up the value in a converting method but they round down in a reading method.
Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: a few more info [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10824) and [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/12705). Basically, `imread` uses codecs internal methods instead of `cvtColor`, so results may differ.

Comment: I fixed the issue in my code by doing this:
To get the same result of imread and cvtColor I had to do this:

    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    img_c=cv2.imread("/home/image_7lbl.png",1) 
    img_g=cv2.imread("/home/image_7lbl.png",0)
    np.array_equal(img_g,img_cg)
    # result: False
    eq=np.array([0.114,0.587,0.299])
    img_m=img_c*eq
    img_mi=img_m.astype(int)
    img_mis=np.sum(img_mi,axis=2)
    np.array_equal(img_g,img_mis)
    #result: True

I think they have to change the code in their library, or there is another explaining to the result.